# Reload vagrant after an update

Tags: mysql, vagrant

What is the fastest method to reload vagrant after changing a provisioning script ?

I am actually copying the file "mysql.sql" to the guest machine, in "Vagrant":

```
config.vm.provision "file", source: "mysql.sql", destination: "mysql.sql"
```

and call it from "bootstrap.sh":

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -proot < /home/vagrant/mysql.sql
```

I used to use:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
vagrant provision
vagrant ssh
```

I tried to see if:

```
vagrant reload
```

will do the same thing, but I am not sure about this, since my modifications happens on the .sql file and not in the Vagrant file.

Comment: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/reload.html suggests a reload with `--provision`. I never tried it, thats why not as an answer.

Comment: vagrant provision works but will reset everything per your provisioning script so if you change for example .zshrc manually and then you have that in your puppet script it will reset it to original.  Just warning

You can also do: `vagrant reload --provision` if you want to restart the machine and reprovision but you can do vagrant provision repeatedly.  This is what I do, change my provision script then run it to see if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run `vagrant reload --provision` to run your [provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/).

***Provision***

> - On the first `vagrant up` that creates the environment, provisioning is run. If the environment was already created and the up is just resuming a machine or booting it up, they won't run unless the `--provision` flag is explicitly provided.
> - When `vagrant provision` is used on a running environment.
> - When `vagrant reload --provision` is called. The --provision flag must be present to force provisioning.

P.S. A bug was fix in Vagrant 1.7.2, if you have a error during `vagrant reload --provision`, you car `rm .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/synced_folders` and after run `vagrant provision`.